# How to update many to many relationship by using id with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I know I can simply update many to many relationship like this:

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('page_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('page.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('pages', lazy=True))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

tag1 = Tag()
tag2 = Tag()
page = Page( tags=[tag1])
```

and later for updating:

```
page.append(tag2)
```

but I want to update them only by the tag id, Assume I have to create a general function that only accepts `person` and `id`s for addresses and update it. 
What I want is something like this:

```
page = Page(tags=[1,2]) # 1 and 2 are primary keys of (tag)s
```

or in a function

```
def update_with_foreignkey(page, tags=[1,2]):
 # dosomething to update page without using Tag object
 return  updated page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a little tricky and by using the evil `eval` but finally, I find a general way to update many to many relations using foreign keys. My goal was to update my object by getting data from a `PUT` request and in that request, I only get foreign keys for the relationship with other data.

### Step by step solution:

1- Find relationships in the object, I find them using `__mapper__.relationships`

2- Find the key that represents the relationship.

```
for rel in Object.__mapper__.relationships:
        key = str(rel).rsplit('.',1)[-1]
```

in question case it return `'tags'` as the result.

3- Find the model for another side of the relation ( in this example `Tag`).
3-1 Find name of the table.
3-2 Convert table name to camleCase because `sqlalchemy` use underscore for the table name and camelCase for the model.
3-3 Use `eval` to get the model.

```
 if key in data:
            table = eval(convert_to_CamelCase(rel.table.name))
            temp = table.query.filter(table.id.in_(data[key])).all() # this line convert ids to sqlacemy objects
```

#### All together

```
def convert_to_CamelCase(word):
    return ''.join(x.capitalize() or '_' for x in word.split('_'))

def update_relationship_withForeingkey(Object, data):
    for rel in Object.__mapper__.relationships:
        key = str(rel).rsplit('.',1)[-1]

        if key in data:
            table = eval(convert_to_CamelCase(rel.table.name))
            temp = table.query.filter(table.id.in_(data[key])).all() # this line convert ids to sqlacemy objects
            data[key] = temp


    return data
```

`data` is what I get from the request, and `Object` is the `sqlalchemy` Model that I want to update.

running this few lines update give me the result:

```
item = Object.query.filter_by(id=data['id'])
data = update_relationship_withForeingkey(Object,data)
for i,j in data.items():
            setattr(item,i,j)
db.session.commit()
```

I'm not sure about caveats of this approach but it works for me. Any improvement and sugesstion are welcome.